# Deploying WAR file with configuration

Tags: java, mysql, config, war

I want to make a WAR file from my project, which uses MySQL-database connectivity. Is there any way I can have an external config file, which then could be updated when I deploy the war file to a Tomcat server?

Comment: Yes you need a property file and based on properties you can run it in different environment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download sql jar file .try this link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc120jar.htm

Download this jar file and add them inside in your project. A sql driver will be installed configure that driver by entering host name, port number, database name, etc.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, but I really want to just have a config file containing things like username, password, host etc. for the database. I use the MySQL Connector/J, by the way.

Comment: @TomasRuud Are you sure you don't want to use a server datasource rather than creating connections directly from your code? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html